# Forming the $N(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have the following solutions $\begin{bmatrix}-3\\ 1\\ 0\\ 1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-2\\ 0\\ -6 \\1\end{bmatrix}$ to $Ax=0$ (nullspace) that makes a 3 by 4 matrix true. How would you create the matrix itself by looking at the solutions? I know a way where you can take the negation but I am having hard time to really grasp the idea and was hoping to see if there is any general way to follow or how you would do it.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a $3 \times 4$ matrix with those vectors in its nullspace, then if $[w,x,y,z]$ is any row of $A$ you can use the nullspace relations to get two equations on the four unknowns $w,x,y,z$, which you can then solved by row reduction. You should check this, but when I did it I got $[w,x,y,z]=[t/2-3s,t/2-9s,s,t].$ Then you can choose various combinations of $s,t$ to make the three rows of $A$. Note that at most two such rows can be independent. And you want to have at least two independent or else there will be more vectors in the nullspace. So you could e.g. use $s=1,t=0$ for row 1, use $s=0,t=1$ for row 2, and then any $s,t$ to make row 3, and then $A$ will have the nullspace you want.